# Will ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection) always close connection?

Tags: c#, .net, database-connection

Is it safe to write this helper method like this? Will it always close the connection? I understend if all goes well, it will, but will ExecuteReader close the connection even if it throws?

```
    public static IEnumerable<DbDataRecord> ExecuteSelect(string commandText, DbConnection conn)
    {
        using (DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = commandText;
            conn.Open();
            using (DbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
            {
                foreach (DbDataRecord record in reader) { yield return record; }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do the answers below help, if it solved your question please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes even if it throws an exception it will close the connection.
If you do not specify `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection` and you close the connection, your calling code cannot access the contents of the reader.

Also from MSDN:

> When the command is executed, the associated Connection object is
>   closed when the associated DataReader object is closed.

You should ensure that the reader is closed when you are done with it.
The nice thing about all of this is you've got it wrapped around a using statement and you aren't using `try/catch/finally` in this case the reader will be closed which then will close the database connection.

Comment: What would be the advantage over using (DbConnection) {using DbDataReader{}} without the CloseConnection option? I like the concept of using because it adds a nice level of self documentation around the code and makes clear (in this case in the calling code) that the connection is no longer open/available afterwards...

Comment: I do not want DbConnection disposed, because this way I do not have to re-create it, which I currently do like `DbConnection conn =  DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(dataProvider).CreateConnection();` and then `conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;`

Comment: @EugeneRyabtsev You shouldn't worry about recreating connections. Connections are *usually* pooled.

Comment: @eFloh - No advantage but it depends on usage.  Many times in a single routine you may open a db connection, execute a reader, use the reader data and then close the connection effectively closing your reader (not allowing any more access of indexing your reader by column name).  This is ok if you are programming a console application or top down programming.  But in most cases we aren't doing a top down approach to programming.  Behind the scenes we have objects interacting with one another requiring is to pass (return) data objects.  With commandbehavior.close we ensure that once the reader.

Comment: ...is closed the connection to the database is closed as well.  Without this type of behavior your connection may stick around for much longer then needed.  These are all minor details but it helps to understand this stuff when you are pulling over a lot of data etc.

Comment: @JonH: thanks for the elaborate answer, these good aspects you are mentioning. Nevertheless, in the case of the using blocks or the case above, I don't see quite an advantage. The main difference is teh fact that using a `using`, you always use new connection objects (maybe pooled), the other way, you may reopen existing connections, what *might* not work with a disposed connection that may be returned multiple times from a factory method.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I prefer a `using` clause statement to *close/dispose* the connection , simply for parallel construction reasons - same as in good English Grammar. 
From my point of view using the `CommandBehavior` is not balanced and therefore unpredictable.

I constantly tell to my developers to go simple and consistent.
As if they forget to set the `CommandBehavior`...

> I won't see it... 
> but if they don't use a **`using`** statement... 
> I **will** see it as it is very important.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will (inside a using block like you're doing).  But to access the data you probably want to use While DbDataReader.read instead of iterating over its contents.

Comment: -1 It will close the connection but NOT because the OP has it inside `using`. I just wrote a simple test and it depends on whether the `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection` is passed in as parameter or not. When not passed in, the connection remains `Open` even after throwing an exception. Remember, `Dispose` won't be called on the Connection itself, since in this particular case, `DBCommand` is enclosed in a `using`, **not** DBConnection

Comment: That's what I meant. To close the connection, even with COmmandBehavior.CloseConnection specified in the constructor, you have to close the reader.  Termination of the Using block will close the reader, in the case of an exception, or completion of the code within the block, no? You can also explicitly call Reader.Close, but you'd have to include a Try/Catch/Finally block

Comment: @Icarus - I don't think its worth down voting this answer, I don't think you interpreted the answer correctly.  The point here is, when a using statement has fulfilled its task it will clean up the resources - in this case the reader is closed.  This follows the MSDN rule that states `When the command is executed, the associated connection object is closed when the associated DataReader object is closed`.  In this case, the using statement closes the reader, and you have explicitly stated `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection`.

Comment: @JonH I will restore my vote once I can. Right now it says that my vote is locked until the answer is edited :(

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is related to closing the connection which will be the case; however, the connection won't be disposed. To dispose the connection itself, you need to enclose it a `using` block as well:

```
using (DBConnection conn = new ...)
{
    using (DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = commandText;
        conn.Open();
        using (DbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
        {
            foreach (DbDataRecord record in reader) { yield return record; }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** I thought this was an interesting question so I wrote the following test:

```
string connString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=msdb;Integrated Security=True;";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);

try
{
using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "select  from MSdbms"; 
        conn.Open();
        Console.WriteLine(conn.State);
        using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())//Will throw an exception - Invalid SQL syntax -see setting CommandText above
        {
            Console.WriteLine("here");
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{  Console.WriteLine(conn.State); } //prints Open
```

If the line `using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())` is changed to: `using (DbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))` then it prints **Closed**. Something to keep in mind.

Comment: So, even if an exception is thrown *before* you open the connection with `conn.Open()`, its `State` is Open? Is this really the case?

Comment: @Patrick It's impossible, at least from the code above, for an exception to be thrown before the connection is opened. None of the lines above `conn.Open()` will cause an `exception` except for `conn.CreateCommand` at which point the connection hasn't been even opened (although it has been instantiated). Only until you call `Open`, the ConnectionString is evaluated to actually establish the connection to the DB.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. Of course, setting the `CommandText` property won't throw an exception, but executing it will. I got confused over the comment at that line.

Comment: @Patrick exactly. The `CommandText` can be gibberish; only when you call `ExecuteReader` will throw the exception.

Comment: Please note NO EXCEPTION is thrown at setting the commandtext.  That code is misleading.  By the way of course it will print closed, its because you passed the enum value `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection`.  The using statement will close the reader as soon as you are finished using it.

Comment: @John I moved the comment to `ExecuteReader`. It was misleading, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you close the reader and/or wrap the reader with `using(var reader ...){}` block **YES** you ensure that your connection is closed.

Not wrapping and doesn't closing the reader with `reader.Close()` kept my connection open.