# already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

Tags: c#

when i am trying to execute the code it is showing the above error.

```
try
{
    com.CommandText = "select * from Export";
    com.ExecuteReader();

    data_mode = "Export";
    com.CommandText = "Insert INTO [" + New_access_file + "]." + data_mode + " select * FROM ExportDATA";
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch
{
    data_mode = "Export";
    com.CommandText = "SELECT * INTO [" + New_access_file + "]." + data_mode + " FROM ExportDATA";
    com.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always call the Close method when you have finished using the DataReader object.

Note that while a DataReader is open, the Connection is in use exclusively by that DataReader. You cannot execute any commands for the Connection, including creating another DataReader, until the original DataReader is closed.

Use this code,

```
var reader = com.ExecuteReader();
//do whatever with reader

reader.Close();
```

**Or**

You can use `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection` for more info [Will ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection) always close connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519273/will-executereadercommandbehavior-closeconnection-always-close-connection). We can use pass it with ExecuteReader method of Command object like

```
var reader = com.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
```

This will make sure that when we are calling reader.Close() the associated connection object will also be closed.

Answer (score 0):

You need an open connection:-

```
try
                {   
                    con.open();

                    com.CommandText = "select * from Export";
                    com.ExecuteReader();

                    data_mode = "Export";
                    com.CommandText = "Insert INTO [" + New_access_file + "]." + data_mode + " select * FROM ExportDATA";
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch
                {
                    data_mode = "Export";
                    com.CommandText = "SELECT * INTO [" + New_access_file + "]." + data_mode + " FROM ExportDATA";
                    com.ExecuteReader();
                }
                 Finally
                 {
                   con.close();
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem. After I spent hours, I found the actual problem for my code. Problem is not actually not using datareader.close() command because I did. Problem is if you're using **ExecuteReader** before datareader it gives that error. Connection.Close() after ExecuteReader does not work either. When I remove ExecuteReader lines from my code, I don't get subject error again.In order to use ExecuteReader lines without problem, I added below codes after ExecuteReader and worked my codes without problem.

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT .......";
string test = cmd.ExecuteReader().ToString();
cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT .........";
DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (DR.Read())
{
   combobox.Items.Add(DR[0]);
}
DR.Close();
```