# Running the same query causing error the second time

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a Data-table with all the mandatory fields which is required by select query in it. Now i am fetching data from 1st row of the data-table and running a select query (as given below). For the first time its working fine. 
Now I am taking the 2nd row and giving all the mandatory fields (as i did for the first) and running the select query its giving error "insufficient permissions". When i am running both the select query (which are actually same but with different parameter) manually in Oracle SQL Developer its working fine.

```
Query1: select cloumnname1 from table where columnname2='valueA' and columnname3= 'VALUEB'
Query2: select cloumnname1 from table where columnname2='valueA' and columnname3= 'VALUEB'
```

To fetch data from database

```
public OracleDataReader ExecuteReader(string SelectQuery, string conString)
        {
        try
        {
            OpenDbConnection(conString);

            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = SelectQuery;
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            OracleDataReader ora_dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            return ora_dataReader;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
```

EDIT:
Forgot to mention that i am calling this funtion in another function as given below

```
public DataTable GetDataFromDB(string SelectQuery, string conString)
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(ExecuteReader(SelectQuery,conString));

                return dt;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseDbConnection();
            }
        }
```

Comment: refactor your Oracle Objects as well as write your query to use parameterized Query, and wrap you connection objects around a `using(){}` structure then you will not need to call the `close()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You need to open and close the connection after each query execution.

And also return the OracleDataReader after you have closed the connection or else it would lead to memory leak. If you return the OracleDataReader before you close connection, you would get the same error.

Try something like this:

```
public OracleDataReader ExecuteReader(string SelectQuery, string conString)
        {
        try
        {
        OpenDbConnection(conString);
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        con.Open(); 
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = SelectQuery;
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        OracleDataReader ora_dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logging.LogMessage(Logging.LogLevel.Error, 0, "DAL", this.GetType().Name, ex.Message + " : " + ex.StackTrace);
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
     con.close();
     con.Dispose(); 
    }

        return ora_dataReader;
}
```

More info in this reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracledatareader(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the database connection and open it again before firing up your second query.

something like:

```
SqlConnection.Open();
```

And

```
SqlConnection.Close();
```

Comment: yes i am doing the same thing in that funtion, still not working

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure you're **closing both the `Connection` and `DataReader` objects**.

Try using the `CommandBehavior` argument in `ExecuteReader`, as it will [close the connection automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10519348/1385268) once you close the `DataReader`.

```
cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
```